# Editing the configuration of a join in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

Is there any way to edit the conditions of an existing join in QGIS? I have a .csv joined to a (polygon) .shp layer; because I only needed a few fields from the .csv, I only joined those I needed.

Now, I'm realizing I need a few more fields--is there any way to edit the current join instead of starting from scratch?

I could also see this being relevant if I decided to change the field by which the tables are joined.

This should be simple but I don't see any options for it.